# Install package paho-mqtt

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install paho-mqtt package for my python project. But it gives the error

```
Error: Python packaging tool 'pip' not found.
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and I am running this command

```
pip install paho-mqtt
```

Can anyone tell me is there another way to install this?

Comment: hi @anjut, it means `pip` is not installed. Do a google search with the words `pip installation <your_os>`

Answer (score 1):

Install pip first, if using python2

`sudo apt-get install python-pip`

or for python3

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Answer (score 0):

Python uses pip to install various Python modules like request, jsonpickel etc.

So you need to install pip first as said by @Asoul